# Python + Sqlite: Add a new column and fill its value at interval of 2

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to add a new column to a `db` file and fill its value at an interval of 2. Here I wrote some codes...

```
import sqlite3

WorkingFile = "C:\\test.db"
con = sqlite3.connect(WorkingFile)

cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("ALTER table MyTable add column 'WorkingID' 'long'") # Add a column "WorkingID" 

rows = cur.fetchall()

iCount = 0
for row in rows:
    iCount = iCount + 2 
    print iCount
    cur.execute("UPDATE MyTable SET WorkingID = ?" , (iCount,)) # Here I have question: How to write the WHERE command?

con.commit()
cur.close()
```

The code above gives me a new Column with same values. Something like this:

```
WorkingID
10
10
10
...
```

But I want a result like this:

```
WorkingID
2
4
6
8
10
...
```

My question on the code is, I dont know how to write the `WHERE` code under `UPDATE`. Would you please help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes it is easier, in the long run (things change), to create your own database from the old one. This gives you carte blanche to create, update, omit, pre-process etc giving you a database specifically tailored to your requirements, rather than fighting with someone else's schema. Just a thought!

Comment: @RolfofSaxony Thanks for the reply. I have to say you are right. Make thing new is more easier than alter it.

Comment: I'm happy to shine a light! :)

Answer (score 1):

The SQL engine cannot tell the difference between the rows.

You should add an [autoincrement](http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html) or ROWID column in order to have it set as ID.

I do not know the structure of your table as you don't create it here but rather alter it.

If you do happen to create it, create a new `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column which you can then use `WHERE` on like so:

```
cur.execute(
    "CREATE TABLE MyTable"
    "(RowID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
    "WorkingID INTEGER)")
```

Comment: The database was originally imported from an excel file, thus I can only alter it. The ROWID method may not be working because I've deleted some rows already, so the ROWID is not consistent. Do you know some other methods?

Answer (score 1):

If your table has some unique ID, get a sorted list of them (their actual values do not matter, only their order):

```
ids = [row[0] for row in cur.execute("SELECT id FROM MyTable ORDER BY id")]
iCount = 0
for id in ids:
    iCount += 2
    cur.execute("UPDATE MyTable SET WorkingID = ? WHERE id = ?",
                [iCount, id])
```

If you don't have such a column, use the `rowid` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't add ID to your table, you can make a really strange way. So..
Before your loop you make a query

```
UPDATE MyTable SET WorkingID = 2 LIMIT 1
```

And after

```
iCount = 2
for row in rows:
    iCount = iCount + 2 
    print iCount
    cur.execute("UPDATE MyTable SET WorkingID = ? WHERE WorkibgID is NULL LIMIT 1" , (iCount,))
```

It's not a good way, but it should work.